# Error en el rango dhcp server debian9

Tags: linux, debian-9

Al ejecutar el comando **journalctl -xe** me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La dirección que estoy usando es
**address 192.168.1.2**

Máscara
**netmask 255.255.255.255**

**Subnet**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar los errores que me salen?

Comment: A simple vista, y comparándolo con uno que tengo aquí, la netmask que yo uso es la 255.255.255.0 en lugar de la 255.255.255.255, y en cuanto al range, yo lo tengo dentro de un `pool{ range 192.168.1.50 192.168.1.200; }` y me funciona bien

Comment: Sí, lo que pasa es que lo intenté con máscaras de tipo C y B y no me daba problemas pero una tipo D no se como quitar el error que me lanza.

Comment: Segun esto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network las de clase D empiezan por 224.0.0.0 (no soy un experto en redes, solo hago que las cosas funcionen o lo parezcan :-))

Comment: Muchas gracias. Le echaré un ojo al link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola veo que estas usando una IP de categoria C (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1scara_de_red)

En teoria la mascara mas tipica para esa ip es 255.255.255.0 basicamente CIDR de 24 (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Si quiers una mascara de categoria D pues tienes que asigunar una subred que le pertenezca como 224.0.0.0

Configuracion tipica /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf :

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
 
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
 option routers 192.168.1.254;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 8.8.8.8;
#option domain-name "mydomain.example";
}
```

Tambien te paso un calculadora que va bien https://jodies.de/ipcalc

Espero que te sea de ayuda.